# get id values from each <th> element

Tags: jquery

Basically I'm trying to call a function `getTableData` that loads a table and places it inside the `div` `tableContents`.

Then what I'm trying to do is get the id values from each `th` that is generated from the function. The table loads with the correct data, but the id values do not alert.  I've even put an alert right after the load and nothing pops...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tableNames').live('click', function (event) {
            $('#tableContents').load(getDBData('getTableData', '', $(this).text()), function () {
           //alert('here');
                $('#tableData th').each(function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    // compare id to what you want
                    alert(id);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
<table id='tableData'>
<tr class='tableHeader'>
<th>Modified</th>
<th id='col1'>col1</th>
<th id='col2'>col2</th>
<th id='col3'>col3</th>
<th id='col4'>col4</th>
<th id='col5'>col5</th>
<th id='col6'>col6</th>
<th id='col7'>col7</th>
<th id='col8'>col8</th>
<th id='col9'>col9</th>
</tr>...

function getDBData(type, dbName, tableName) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajaxDBReturn.asp?type="+ type + "&dbName=" + dbName + "&tableName=" + tableName,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            if(type == "getTables")
            {
                //result = "<table id='tableList'>" + result + "</table>";
                ($("#tableList").html(result));
            } else if (type == "getTableData") {
                ($("#tableContents").html(result));
            }else if (type == "getTableRelationship"){
                result = "<table id='listTableBody'>" + result + "</table>";
            }



        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Did you check whether this TABLE HEADER elements contain id ?

Comment: Do you have $(document).ready(function() {} ) before all ?

Comment: Yes the TH has an id value and I wrapped everything in the $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: @lam3r4370: Since OP stated that *the table loads with the correct data*, I'm guessing that's not the issue.

Comment: @Jeff V: Can you add to your question a sample of the markup from the new table?

Comment: Can you show us the first piece of the table?

Comment: @Jeff V: Do you have more than one element with the same ID `tableData`? Are you certain that the table returned has that ID?

Comment: @Jeff V: Can you `alert()` in the success function?

Comment: There are no duplicate id's with the small set of data that I'm using so far.

Comment: @Jeff V: When you say *"I've even put an alert right after the load..."*, do you mean in the callback, or after the entire `load()` call?

Comment: @Jeff V: What does getDBData return? Only a link right?

Comment: @Marnix - builds a full table from scratch.

Comment: @patrick dw - I updated my post to include the original alert statement.

Comment: and that didn't pop anything either.

Comment: @Jeff V: Any errors in the console? Is there any code that is being excluded in the callback? Any chance this code was copy/pasted? If so, delete the entire `.load()` function, and re-type it.

Comment: Try using var id = $(this).Id; instead of var id = $(this).attr("id")

Comment: ...also, I assume the `getDBData` function returns a URL string. Is that right?

Comment: @patrick dw: I'm assuming that the `getDBData` is creating the table itself. It will not return a string and will apply the data itself to the document. This means that the `load` isn't wanted here at all.

Comment: Just making sure ... <th id=col1>col1</th> is missing quotes around the id? does you output HTML have the quotes?

Comment: @Marnix: That could be. We're definitely missing a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @Bobby - fixed the quotes around the id and still nothing.
@patrick dw - getDBData builds the table. I'm using classic ASP and building the table using response.writes.  I'll update my post to include the function as well.

Comment: you guys pretty much have everything now...  :)

Comment: Jeff V: If `getDBData` is building the table, then *how* does it build it? Does it make a request to the server? If so, you should use [the answer from `@Marnix`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415319/get-id-values-from-each-th-element/6415714#6415714), and pass a callback into the function, and assign that callback to the `success` callback of the server request.

Comment: I'll have to play around with it to see what I can do.  My issue is that the id's will not pop.  My theory is that the table or the id's aren't yet there at the time of the .click event...

Comment: Jeff V: Use the answer from @Marnix. It is entirely correct. You need to place the `.each()` with the alerts in the `success:` callback to the `$.ajax` function. Either hard code them in, or pass a function that gets called inside `success:` like @Marnix is doing.

Comment: ...the way it is right now, your `getDBData` function is returning `undefined` to `.load()`. The `.load()` method simply has nothing to do with what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @patrick - Thanks.  I got it to work based off of that recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I've read [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/) quickly. Your `.load()` function should get an `url` and not a complete piece of data. If you do, that could result into no actual adding to your data, because the `load()` method doesn't load a thing if it doesn't get a string with an url.

If you getDBData adds it itself, then there is no `succes`. You should give your succes function to your getDBData instead and invoke the function after you're done building your table.

If this is the case, I would recommend a simple global function call like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('.tableNames').live('click', function (event) 
    {
        // here is the change
        // do you really need to call $('#tableContents')?
        // you are probably also doing that in the function itself.
        // also give your success function to your home-made function
        getDBData('getTableData', '', $(this).text(), function()
        {
            $('#tableData th').each(function () 
            {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                // compare id to what you want
                alert(id);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 I think this is most likely the issue, given the information presented so far.

Comment: I actually had very similar code to this originally...  Everything worked but the id's didn't pop.  I used load because I wanted the table to be there 1st and then loop through the table for the ids.

Comment: Thanks to @marnix and @patrick and everyone else that contributed...  Once I moved the alert into the success function of the AJAX call then I got the results I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

If `#tableData` doesn't exist when the page renders, or if it exists but doesn't have any `th` elements when the page renders, then the `each` function will have nothing to iterate over. If `#tableData` is created or modified when your data is loaded, then you'll need to use `delegate` to bind your function to it.

Comment: The each is in the callback of load, which I believe he is saying creates that table.

Comment: +1 to what @kingjiv wrote, plus `.delegate()` wouldn't work anyway. It's only useful for invoking event handlers.

Comment: @patrick dw yes I see that now... I posted my answer before OP's numerous updates to his question.